# multilingual website using aws

Tags: java, angularjs, amazon-web-services

We are planning to create a multilingual website using angular js and aws. The site will have dynamic data from back end.  What will be the best approach? Whether to store language specific data separately in db or use a translation service to convert same data to different language.

The application needs to support mobile platform also. So we are planning to send all data in JSON format. Will a json encode/decode is a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  does not make much sense storing localized data. The best approach would be to use `angular-translate` module. The source and documentation can be found here https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will check and will let you know.

Comment: Sorry I guess I missed to mention about the mobile platform support. The application needs to support android and ios. So everything send over is in the format of json. Will the json encoding decoding be a good solution?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But using JSON with keys which act as the message placeholder in the app and the actual translated as the values for the keys is the most common practice and it works well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was looking at both static and dynamic content in the application. For static content your solution works well. But for dynamic content I think we need to have separate tables holding textual data.